# c++ function call - pass by reference calls pointer method / pass by value calls referense method

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

A function call is made in the code. In the first function call a pass by reference is performed calling the pointer function. In the second function call a pass by value is performed where the reference function is called.

Why is this so?

```
#include <iostream>
void f(int *p) { (*p)++; }
void f(int &p) { p-=10; }
int main() {
 int x=0; f(&x); f(x); f(&x);
 std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `f(&x)` is not passing by reference, it is using the address-of operator to get the objects address. Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is an `int` variable.  `&x` is taking the address of `x`, yielding an `int*` pointer.

`f(&x)` can't pass an `int*` pointer to an `int&` reference, but it can pass to an `int*` pointer, so it calls:

`void f(int*)`

`f(x)` can't pass an `int` variable to an `int*` pointer, but it can pass to an `int&` reference, so it calls:

`void f(int&)`

Comment: thanks a lot i learn a lot from this